# How to remove a JSONObject from forming in this example

Tags: java, json

I am creating a JSON dynamically using org.json

This is the output i am getting currently

```
{
    "item": {
        "T1": [
            {
                "name": "101",
                "T2": {
                    "leaf": [
                        {
                            "jsonkey": "jsonval"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**I need the output to be in this format**

(Removed the extra T2 JSONObject )

```
{
    "item": {
        "T1": [
            {
                "name": "101",
                "leaf": [
                    {
                        "jsonkey": "jsonval"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This is my whole program

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
        Map<String,LinkedList<JSONObject>> vendorOrdersMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,LinkedList<JSONObject>>();
        JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject();
        jsonobj.put("jsonkey", "jsonval");
        LinkedList<JSONObject> listjson = new LinkedList<JSONObject>();
        listjson.add(jsonobj);
        vendorOrdersMap.put("101", listjson);
        JSONObject sai = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray T1Array = new JSONArray();
        for (Map.Entry<String, LinkedList<JSONObject>> entry : vendorOrdersMap.entrySet())
        {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            LinkedList<JSONObject> t1ChildList = entry.getValue();
            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray();
            for(JSONObject t2ColumnData : t1ChildList)
            {
                jsonarray.put(t2ColumnData);
                JSONObject lemon = new JSONObject().put("leaf", jsonarray);
                JSONObject soft = new JSONObject().put("name", key).put("T2", lemon);
                T1Array.put(soft);
            }
            JSONObject softDrink = new JSONObject().put("T1", T1Array);
            sai.put("item", softDrink);
        }
        System.out.println(sai);
    }
```

If i remove that

```
JSONObject soft = new JSONObject().put("name", key).put("T2", lemon);
```

i am not able to append the data .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you change the innermost `for`-loop to something like

```
jsonarray.put(t2ColumnData);
JSONObject soft = new JSONObject().put("name", key).put("leaf", jsonarray);
T1Array.put(soft);
```

because you want to keep the `name` part and only replace the `T2` part with its child.

Comment: This is exactly what i needed , thank you very very much , i am strugling on this earlier .